# CodeIgniter re-routing controller

Tags: codeigniter, routes

Is there way of routing controllers in CodeIgniter such that a controller with a url like `path/controllerA/some_method` becomes `/some_name/some_method_ofA` where *some_name* is controller A without moving controller A?

I can do this properly with one method of controller a via:

`$route['some_name/(:any)'] = '/path/controllerA/some_method/$1';`

but I can't seem to get it so that some_name is basically an alias for controller A such that I can access other methods.

So before: *path/controllerA/some_method_ofA, path/controllerA/some_method_ofA2*

After: */some_name/some_method_ofA, /some_name/some_method_ofA*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set it up:

```
$route['signin'] = 'Contact/SignIn'; //Maybe that, controller contact and method SignIn
$route['page/(:any)'] = 'Post/index/$1';
```

You just need to use:

```
$route['new_url'] = 'Controller/method';
```

Comment: but essentially that means i need a route for every method of the controller correct?

Comment: Yes, if you want to change url, you have to set it up.

Comment: I think lower case in your routes.php is better

Comment: Yes, I think so too. Thank you.